# Spring boot with a reactive mongodb keeps trying to connect to localhost

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, spring-webflux

I've a reactive Spring boot API/MongoDB which I wanted to dockerize, but the Spring-boot app keeps trying to connect to mongoDB on localhost:21017. Which obviously gives me a connection refused back.

All the options I tried like excluding the autoconfiguring-classes, overriding the reactiveMongoTemplate, nothing seems to work out. I would love to hear some suggestions

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    hostname: spring
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    container_name: "review-service"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    hostname: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo_review
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

app-properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

Application.class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class, MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class ConferenceAppReviewReactiveApplication extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner  {
    @Autowired
    private ReviewService reviewService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConferenceAppReviewReactiveApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Review review = new Review();
        review.setRev_referenceId("60d093a31ee645007b2df2cb");
        reviewService.save(review);
    }
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create();
    }
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://mongo:27017/test");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! For me, this was enough: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude=MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class)`. I setup mongo connection myself.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found:

- Removed all the configuration (extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration)
- Removed all the excludes

Apparently @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories is enough, Spring will do the rest